# React-Table with Typescript: Make the whole header group stick to the top when scrolling

Tags: css, typescript, react-table

I have a header group in my table and I want the table to be scrollable. I put the `position: sticky` in the table . When I put the `overflow: scroll;` in the CSS for the container, the header sticks to the top like I want it to but it won't show the second line of the header group anymore.

Header Group:

```
    {
        Header: 'Author',
        columns: [
            {
                Header: 'First Name',
                accessor: 'author_first',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Last Name',
                accessor: 'author_last'
            }
        ],
    },
```

without the `overflow: scroll;`

[image]

with:

[image]

I put the `overflow: scroll` in the according container:

```
    .table-container {
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    height: 600px;
    width: 90%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

and call the Table like this:

```
<div className='table-container'>
   <Table />
</div>
```

my table th:

```
table th {
    position: sticky; /* Keep the table head when scrolling */
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

Remember that position sticky generate a sticky element ONLY on scrollable parent container, so the parent container MUST be a scrollable element

Good luck

```js
const body = document.querySelector(".body");

for (let x = 0; x < 300; x++) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.innerHTML = "<td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td>";
    body.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>data</th>
      <th>data</th>
      <th>data</th>
      <th>data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body"></tbody>
</table>
```